cargar en un combo cuando los dato son pk(en la clase persona tiene un Documento documento1)
[![aqui está el evento que es el click de agregar][1]][1]
creo que se hace con una lista pero nose la verdad gracias¡¡
private void btnGrabar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Persona persona1 = new Persona();
persona1.Nombres = txtNombres.Text;
persona1.Apellido = txtApellido.Text;
persona1.Documento = Convert.ToInt32(txtDocumento.Text);
persona1.Sexo = rbtFemenino.Checked ? 1 : 2;
persona1.Fallecio = chkFallecio.Checked;
persona1.FechaNacimiento = dtpFechaNacimiento.Value;

//falta agregar tipo_documento y estado_civil que no se como


helper.AgregarSQL(persona1);

}
public bool AgregarSQL(Persona persona)
{
bool result = false;
 cnn.Open();
     string query = "INSERT INTO personas (apellido, nombre, tipo_documento, documento, estado_civil, sexo, fallecido, fecha_nacimiento) " +
                    "VALUES (@apellido, @nombre, @tipo_documento, @documento, @estado_civil, @sexo, @fallecido, @fecha_nacimiento)";

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
 



     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apellido", persona.Apellido);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", persona.Nombres);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo_documento", persona.documento1.id_tipo_documento);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@documento", persona.Documento);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado_civil", persona.estado_Civil1.id_estado_civil);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexo", persona.Sexo);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fallecido", persona.Fallecio);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_nacimiento", persona.FechaNacimiento);
 
     result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1;
 cnn.Close();


 return result;

}

(1) Explicar el problema y cuál es el comportamiento esperado.- (2) El código va como texto, no como imagen.- (3) Quitar la etiqueta java que al parecer no tiene nada que ver con tu pregunta
